# AccessViolation error while using _tcstok in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to run the following code

```
TCHAR* str1 = TEXT("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer;");     
const TCHAR* del = TEXT(";");        
TCHAR* token = _tcstok(str1, del);
```

When I run this in VS 2010 I get the following Exception :
Unhandled exception at 0x10275af4 (msvcr100d.dll) in String_Tchars.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0041839c.

My Objecttive to to be able to get the part before the semi-colon ";" and then do an append to that token to get the final string as  c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

Could someone shed some light what is causing this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `strtok()` (and its Windows relatives) with modifiable strings. So make your strings local character arrays:

```
TCHAR str1[] = TEXT("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer;");
TCHAR* token = _tcstok(str1, ";");
// etc.
```

The the tokenizer function actually modifies the string by replacing the delimiter by null bytes, so there's no way you can use this on a read-only string.

If your string comes to you through a pointer-to-const, copy it to a local array first (e.g. to a `std::vector<TCHAR>`):

```
void foo(const TCHAR * str)
{
  std::vector<TCHAR> s(str, _tcslen(str) + 1);  // local copy, includes null terminator
  TCHAR * str1 = s.data();  // or &s[0]
  TCHAR* token = _tcstok(str1, ";");
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Als and Kerrek SB , it was really helpful and I did not run into the issue after following your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

`_tcstok` tries to modify the constant string(string Literal) causing an **Undefined Behavior**, which presents itself in the form of an access violation.

The **string Literal** I refer to here is:

```
TCHAR* str1 = TEXT("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer;"); 
       ^^^^
```

The program should not modify it, and `_tcstok` tries to do that hence the **Undefined Behavior**.

Instead use modifyable non const string array:

```
TCHAR str1[] = TEXT("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer;");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response . I did try without the 'const' specifier and had the same crash . So how do I use this function?

Comment: @Prakash: Updated the answer to answer your query.